# Connecting Canon camera using EDSDK (or not) via network

Tags: camera, canon-sdk

I am using EDSDK in my app, its working with camera via usb well, but official Android/iOS application from Canon ( in official SDK there is no network support, they used some inaccessable stuff for us) and third-party android-software "DSLR Controller" (How they did it!?) can operate camera via network. Is there a way (or workaround) to connect to Canon EOS camera using via network? As a result of using the official SDK connection to the camera is transparent and USB-only...

Answer (score 2):

Only a limited number of cameras can be used with Wifi (e.g. the 6D) with the SDK. But those supported can be controlled with the official SDK (on Windows and Mac OS X only, though).

I do not know what the official apps use but as far as I know there is no SDK publicly available for that. The ED SDK certainly does not support neither Android nor iOS.

The DSLR Controller app is, as far as I know, using a custom implementation that has been reverse engineered. Therefore it is not dependent on the SDK and can be used wherever they choose to implement it.

Comment: In an official SDK, I found nothing about the wi fi, network .... only PTP via USB. Given that there is no support for OTG Background on Windows platform and I have 6D I want to try to befriend them via WIFI. You said that the 6D can be controlled via the WIFI... I tried everything available to me through the Digital Imaging Developer Program and have not found anything ... what I missed?

Comment: @DmitryTsyganov yeah, the documentation is not really up to date and you can't rely on it completely. Have you tried to use the EOS Utility with a Wifi camera? It uses the SDK as well so if it works there you should be able to replicate it with your own code.

Comment: sorry, I'm not quite correctly wrote. I want to create an application for Widows Phone, so experiment with EOS Utility hardly give any result...

Comment: There is no way to connect camera to Windows Phone device via usb and i have 6D. I tried to listen traffic between Android device and my 6D. They create UPNP chat, but I have yet got to listen to the traffic service, serving this chat. About what is happening inside it is still unknown, but probably will learn later. Now there are 2 options. The first - with SDK to generate commands for the camera and try to connect with the camera and send them via WIFI insted of USB. Second -  take Android device, catch all network traffic on each event and try to reproduce on WP. What can you advise?

Comment: @DmitryTsyganov, oh I see. You'll have to reverse engineer the commands then but I can't help you there. But as a start, Canon uses PTP as a basis (at least for USB connections) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: you said that documentation is not up to date. In documentation there is nothing about wifi... May be there is a undocumented way to connect camera via wifi to PC using canon SDK in C# custom application? (or with optional wrappers...etc..)

Comment: @DmitryTsyganov, none that I know of, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to [download](https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/?id=jp.co.canon.ic.cameraconnect) the Canon's official [Camera Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.canon.ic.cameraconnect) APK, extract shared libraries (.so files) form it, since APK is a zip package. Then you can try to create a wrapper around those libraries, since they provide static methods with same name as in the official Canon EOS SDK, for example EDSInitialize, EDSRelease

I was able to successfully call EDSInitialize and EDSRelease methods, but failed to enumerate connected (via OTG cable) camera.

Comment: Hi @Ladislav, Do you know if CCSDK works with the Canon EOS 6D over wifi or does it work only with the PowerShot SX70 for now - trying to connect from a windows system ?

Comment: Hello @aviimaging!

Unfortunately the new API SDK by Canon will work only with SX70 and all their new future models. They do not plan to support any older models.
I simply know, because I asked them and the answer was clear: NO.

But you still can try MSYS2/MinGW with GPhoto2 on Windows to programatically access Canon camera features - just google for it ;)

Comment: @Ladislav were you finally able to make this extarcted so wrapper working on Android?

Comment: @cubesoft no, not really.
When I call the EDSSomethingXXX method, which should return the number of connected cameras, it returns 0 even if have connected my camera.
I also asked the authors of some DSLR applications available on Play Store whether they plan to publish their stuff as an SDK library but they answer was again NO.